# How to prevent Ubuntu from throwing error after removing the USB keyboard?

Tags: usb, keyboard

I use a USB switcher to control multiple Ubuntu, which means it electronically (like shorting it almost I guess, maybe, not entirely sure) unplug the USB without removing the USB device physically from the machine after I switch from one machine to another. A harmless but annoying thing is after I switch, the system will throw error like:

```
[123] usb 1-1.1-portx: cannot reset
[124] usb 1-1.1-portx: cannot reset
[125] usb 1-1.1-portx: cannot reset
[126] usb 1-1.1-portx: cannot reset
[127] usb 1-1.1-portx: cannot reset
[128] usb 1-1.1-portx: cannot reset
```

Of course this won't actually does harm to any service running on the machine but kind annoying to see on the screen, is there a way to prevent it from happening?

I tried modifying `/etc/sysctl.conf` and in which I uncomment `kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3` to stop low-level messages on console, and then reboot, yet the messages persists.

Comment: Stop using the USB device before switching and it shouldn't give any error message.

Comment: @heynnema that would add additional human actions...which in term would be somewhat a bigger issue...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a kernel message. I would lower the kernel log level in the console:

From https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console

In the file /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# Uncomment the following to stop low-level messages on console
kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3
```

Comment: I tried modifying `/etc/sysctl.conf` and in which I uncomment `kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3` to stop low-level messages on console, and then reboot, yet the messages persists.

Comment: @AeroWindwalker maybe you will have to lower the level even more using different numbers. The linked question will tell you how to do it.